# Как работает exception.localizedMessage

Tags: android, kotlin

Я пытаюсь вывести в лог локализованное сообщение от exception:

```
task.exception?.let { it1 ->Log.e("Debug",it1.localizedMessage)}
```

На виртуальном устройстве у меня установлена русская локализация, все иконки меню на русском языке. Но в лог, почему-то я получаю сообщение на английском.
В документации написано, что нужно метод localizedMessage переопределить, чтобы выдал сообщение на локальном языке, а без переопределения работает как метод message, то есть на английском.
Только в интернете нет нигде примера, как нужно этот метод переопределить.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если кто знает.

Comment: Как хотите, так и переопределяйте - примеров нет потому что все забили, текст сообщения об ошибке нужно только самому программисту и программист с этим не заморачивается, так как ему больше важна трассировка, а не текст ошибки. Ну и любой прогер априори обязан знать инглиш хотя бы минимально, надо больше - переводчик/словарь в помощь. Саму локализацию, при желании, вы можете сделать точно так же, как и локализацию всех текстов приложения: `context.getString(R.string.error_message)`.

Comment: Я знаю английский, вопрос не в этом. Я хотел соощение об ошибке выводить в Toast для пользователя на его языке, а не прописывать для каждого exception свой R.string на разных языках. Я подумал, что метод localizedMessage как раз это и делает автоматом, определив язык устройсва, возвращает сообщение на нужном языке. А похоже, что он создан, чтобы я сам его переопределил и сообщения перевел, тогда не понимаю, нафиг он нужен вообще, если всё равно самому тексты сообщенний прописывать

Comment: Так а откуда он их может взять - по-любому тексты своих собственных исключений для всех языков должны заготовить вы. А разработчики ОС и библиотек не считают целесообразным их локализовать, хотя изредка такое встречается. Самое поганое, что зачастую `localizedMessage` вообще не содержит сообщения даже на инглише.